# Extract strings from a Dataframe looping over a single row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, extract

I'm reading multiple PDFs (using tabula) into data frames like this:

```
nan = float('nan')
DataFrame_as_dict = {'Unnamed: 0': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan},
 'Unnamed: 1': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan},
 'NOTA DE NEGOCIAÇÃO': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: 'Rico Investimentos - Grupo XP',
  3: 'Av. Presidente Juscelino Kubitschek - Torre Sul, 1909 - 25o ANDAR VILA OLIMPIA 4543-907',
  4: 'Tel. 3003-5465Fax: (55 11) 4007-2465',
  5: 'Internet: www.rico.com.vc SAC: 0800-774-0402 e-mail: atendimento@rico.com.vc'},
 'Unnamed: 3': {0: 'Nr. nota Folha',
  1: '330736 1',
  2: nan,
  3: 'SÃO PAULO - SP',
  4: nan,
  5: nan},
 'Unnamed: 4': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan},
 'Unnamed: 5': {0: 'Data pregão',
  1: '30/09/2015',
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan}}

df = pd.DataFrame(DataFrame_as_dict)
```

[dataframe figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Poigw.png)

My intention is to use that value '330736 1' into the variable "number" and '30/09/2015' into a variable "date".

The issue is that, although these values will always be located in row 1, ***the columns vary*** in an unpredictable way across the multiple PDFs.

Therefore, I tried to loop over the different columns of row 1, in order to extract these data regardless the columns they are:

```
list_columns = df.columns
for i in range(len(list_columns)):
    if isinstance(df.iloc[1:2,i], str):
        if df.iloc[1:2,i].str.contains("/",na=False,regex=False).any():
            date = str(df.iloc[1:2,i]).strip()
        else:
            n_nota = str(df.iloc[1:2,i]).strip()
```

However, without success... Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original code, `if isinstance(df.iloc[1:2,i], str)` will never evaluate to `True` for two reasons:

1. Strings inside DataFrames are of type `object`
2. `df.iloc[1:2,i]` will always be a pandas Series.

Since `object` is such a flexible type, it's not as useful as `str` for identifying the data you want.  In the code below, I simply used a space character to differentiate the data you want for `n_nota`.  If this doesn't work with your data, a regex pattern may be a good approach.

```
list_columns = df.columns
for i in range(len(list_columns)):
    if isinstance(df.iloc[1:2,i].values, object):
        (df.iloc[1:2,i].values)
        if "/" in str(df.iloc[1:2,i].values):
            date = str(df.iloc[1:2,i].values[0]).strip()
        elif " " in str(df.iloc[1:2,i].values):
            n_nota = str(df.iloc[1:2,i].values[0]).strip()
```

Edit:  As noted below, the original code in the question text would have worked if each `df.iloc[1:2,i]` were replaced with `df.iloc[1,i]` as in:

```
list_columns = df.columns
for i in range(len(list_columns)):
    if isinstance(df.iloc[1,i], str):
        if df.iloc[1:2,i].str.contains("/",na=False,regex=False).any():
            date = str(df.iloc[1,i]).strip()
        else:
            n_nota = str(df.iloc[1,i]).strip()
```

Comment: Your code worked wonderfully. Thank you very much. 
However, when you say "will never evaluate to True" I thought it would because when I tested
" print(isinstance(df.iloc[1, 5], str)) " it printed True.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense @Allan, and leads to the more logical solution I added above which is almost identical to your proposed solution. Bravo!  You were obviously very nearly there, and this edited solution doesn't rely on the less general space character.